# Sublime Text 3: Prevent file from opening in a new tab on right mouse click in the sidebar

Tags: sublimetext3

Is it possible to prevent Sublime Text 3 from opening a file automatically in a new tab when performing a right mouse click on a file from within the sidebar?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. Go to `Preferences-->Settings` and edit your user setting, add one option:

```
"preview_on_click": false,
```

It will prevent file from opening in the tab when you right click on it. Also, as a side effect, when you left click on a file in the sidebar, it will not open in the tab. You have to double click it to open the file on tab.